# Is it possible to somehow "hold" the return-value of Mockitos when...then construct in a temp-variable?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, mockito

I have a ServiceClass and a RepositoryClass, from Service I want to test one (real) method, Repository I want to mock.

I'll give an example:

```
class PersonService {
  private final PersonRepository personRepository;

  public void manipulateData(Person p){
    p.setName("Martin");
    personRepository.save(p);
  }
}
```

Now I would like to verify, if the serviceClass manipulated my object as expected. For that I would like to do the following:

```
@Mock
PersonRepository personRepository; 

PersonService personService;

Person p = new Person("Josef");

when(personRepository.save(any())).***thenStoreThisValueInMyTempFieldAbove***
personService.manipulateData(p);
when(personRepository.find(any()).thenReturn(p);

assertThat(p.getName).equals("Martin");
```

Is something like my when...then-construct possible?
What other way is there to test Service Methods with mocked repository when they have no return value and when the database would be the only place to get that Object and verify its correctness?

Comment: You've already got a reference to `p` so you will just see the changes that personService makes to it anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ArgumentCaptor.

You can define a captor like below:

```
@Captor
private ArgumentCaptor<Person> personCaptor;
```

Then you can capture the value while calling your repo method.

```
when(personRepository.save(personCaptor.capture()));
```

Finally you can use the captured value to assert like:

```
assertEquals("Martin", personCaptor.getValue().getName())
```

Reference: https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-argumentcaptor